# Distinguishing finished and ongoing tag clean up/retag request

Tags: discussion, tags

There are many retag requests and tag clean-ups going on in Meta.SO, some have finished [a], some are in progress [b], some are under discussion [c] and some have been decided as invalid [d].

I currently can think of a few options to categorize them so that people don't waste their time looking at requests that have been long done [a].

- **Meta status tags**: Flag for [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) for all requests that have finished [a], [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for declined requests [d]. <s>This only distinguishes finished requests [a] among the 4 status of a request</s> This adds workload to the moderators, who are already busy. The tag is visible only when people search for tag-related requests and the front page where tags are displayed. The advantage is that it is always possible to add the tag to the question, albeit inconvenient.
- **Accepted answer**: Create an answer (wiki if the task is not done by you), and ask the author of the question to accept it for [a] and [d]. It has higher visibility, since questions with accepted answer will be marked green with yellow text everywhere. It can distinguish [a] and [d], which have been settled, apart from [b] and [c], which are ongoing. However, the OP may have been long gone, and it is not possible to make the question appears accepted. And when there is a change in opinion in request that was deemed invalid, it is not always possible to change the accepted answer or remove the accepted check mark.
- **Vote to close**: Close all finished requests [a] (but not [d], to allow the discussion to be revived later). There is generally no need to reopen such questions, since re-tagging and tag cleanup, if done, are not reversible and any discussion belongs to a new question. Closing question can be done by any user with enough privilege, and the status of [a] will be visible everywhere, since [Closed] is appended to the question title.

What do you guys think? Feel free to propose your ideas.

**Note:** I don't tag this question with [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) or [clean-up](/questions/tagged/clean-up), since it is not a request, but rather a discussion about it.

Comment: The way [su] does this is this: nothing for requests being discussed, [meta-tag:status-completed] for done requests, [meta-tag:status-planned] for in progress requests, and [meta-tag:status-declined] for declined requests.

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi Does that not require moderator intervention of Super User?

Comment: @thegrinner It does, and **that's completely intended**. See here: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8146/help-us-clean-up-tags

Comment: @damryfbfnetsi: Not sure whether the mods at SO have time for that. Tag clean ups are usually done by normal users with little intervention from mods (unless the tag has too many questions). SO has high volume of craps which takes most of the time that mods over here.

Comment: I think that [su] has a bigger tag problem than [so]. I think you should maybe talk to its mods in its chat room for talking to moderators.